# Como alterar a ordem da legenda, sem alterar as cores do gráfico no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou montando esse gráfico utilizando o pacote ggplot2 e prefiro ele com cores mais neutras como na primeira imagem (sem cores vibrantes), porém quando modifico a ordem da legenda as cores do gráfico são modificadas também, passando para as da segunda imagem.

"Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will
replace the existing scale."

Esse é o retorno quando tento adicionar o comando de alterar a ordem da legenda quando já tenho as cores que quero definidas.

Segue o script sem o código para alterar a ordem da legenda:

`ggplot(data=dfDNA, aes(x=Spp, y=Prop, fill=Elementos)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + xlab("Espécies")+ylab("Proproção") + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Elementos Repetitivos"))`

Segue o comando para alterar a ordem das legendas:

`+ scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("Gypsy", "Copia", "LINE", "SINE", "Transposons", "DNA Satélite", "Sem Classificação"))`

[image: Imagem 1 com as cores que quero pois assim consigo diferenciar melhor todos os elementos do gráfico como LINE e SINE]

[image: Imagem 2 de como a legenda deve ficar, porém com cores inadequadas]

Comment: Você pode definir as cores manualmente: 'scale_color_manual(values = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF", "#FC4E07"))'

Comment: @Daniel infelizmente não funcionou também. Não retornou nada e nem alterou as cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trocar a ordem da legenda, basta trocar a ordem dos níveis da variável `fill` em `scale_fill_brewer` com o argumento `breaks`.
Em baixo está um exemplo com a base `mtcars`. O gráfico da esquerda tem a legenda na ordem usual, o gráfico da direita troca os itens `4` e `8`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

data(mtcars)

g1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = vs, y = carb, fill = factor(carb))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Por ordem"))

g2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = vs, y = carb, fill = factor(carb))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", breaks = c(1:3, 8, 6, 4)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Trocar 4 e 8"))


grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu super certo utilizando o argumento ```breaks``` para escolher a ordem em  ```scale_fill_brewer```. Valeu mesmo.